# Cannot copy text in tmux mode in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, tmux, centos-7

Do you know how I can copy text in tmux mode in CentOS 7?
[image]

When I select the text, it shows as yellow but cannot copy it.

This is what I have in tmux.conf:
[image]

If I press shift while selecting, it will show as white but then I cannot right-click to copy neither CTL+C or CTL+SHIFT+C would work for copy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu, and I have xclip (so for you, `yum install xclip`) installed on
my system and have the following in my .tmux.conf which allows me to begin
copying (having pressed `Ctrl` + `b` then `[`) by pressing `v` and to paste the
copied stuff to the system clipboard with `y`:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -sel clip -i'
```

Note that this is for vi mode, but I assume if you change it to:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-emacs v send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-emacs y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -sel clip -i'
```

it will work the same way.